# Инициализация бина при старте приложения spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

есть бин, который надо положить в сессию когда клиент подключается к сайту.
думал в контроллере сделать метод index который отправляет главную страницу, но тогда если клиент зайдет на сайт с другой страницы, моего бина не будет.
        как это можно реализовать? есть ли в spring метод init для всех контроллеров?
на данный момент это реализовано так

```
 @RequestMapping(value = {"/index","/"})
    public String index(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        httpServletRequest.getSession().setAttribute("hello","hello");
        return "index";
    }
```

Comment: В спринге есть @SessionScope для бина.

Comment: @aleshka-batman а как его тогда получить в jsp с помощью ${sessionScope}?

Comment: @aleshka-batman эту аннотацию я поставил

Comment: Делаете бин обычным классом с сеттерами/геттерами. А затем в жсп достаете из него то, что вам необходимо. ${myBean.field}

Comment: Метод `init` уесть сервлета. Насколько мне известно у спринга это диспатчер сервлет.